# when switching the radio buttons show the different content using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I need to build a UI using angularjs where there are two radio buttons "Personal" and "official".
When personal is clicked show the content as shown in attached image.
[image]

When Official radio button is clicked show content as shown in below image.
[image]

I tried it using table but did not work, hence it will be help if small is provided for same.

Thanks

Comment: use `ng-if` or `ng-switch` (if you will have more than 2 buttons) to switch the content within them

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey - tried with ng-show but did not work.

Comment: you should post the code that you tried